# Наследование методов для кнопок Java

Tags: java

Всем привет! прошу вашей помощи. Недавно начал изучать adf и javа и не как не могу разобраться с наследованием методов для кнопок.В приложении есть 10 таблиц для каждой таблицы есть кнопка вызывающая диалоговое окно,в котором я добавляю данные в таблицу код:

```
public class Main {
public Main() {
    super();
}

public void editPopupFetchListener(PopupFetchEvent popupFetchEvent) {
    if (popupFetchEvent.getLaunchSourceClientId().contains("cbInsert")) {  //cbInsert это id кнопки
        BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
        OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("CreateInsert");
        operationBinding.execute();
    }
}

public void editDialogListener(DialogEvent dialogEvent) {
    if (dialogEvent.getOutcome().name().equals("ok")) {
        BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
        OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("Commit");
        operationBinding.execute();   
    } else if (dialogEvent.getOutcome().name().equals("cancel")) {
        BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
        OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("Rollback");
        operationBinding.execute();
    }
}

public void editPopupCancelListener(PopupCanceledEvent popupCanceledEvent) {
    BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
    OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("Rollback");
    operationBinding.execute();
}

public BindingContainer getBindings() {
    return BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
}
}
```

окно вызывается при нажатии кнопки с id "cbInsert",но если появляется еще одна кнопка то тогда меняться и id например "cbInsert1" и на данный момент у меня получается это так

```
public class Main {
public Main() {
    super();
}

public void editPopupFetchListener(PopupFetchEvent popupFetchEvent) {
    if (popupFetchEvent.getLaunchSourceClientId().contains("cbInsert")) {
        BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
        OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("CreateInsert");
        operationBinding.execute();
    }
}

public void editDialogListener(DialogEvent dialogEvent) {
    if (dialogEvent.getOutcome().name().equals("ok")) {
        BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
        OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("Commit");
        operationBinding.execute();   
    } else if (dialogEvent.getOutcome().name().equals("cancel")) {
        BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
        OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("Rollback");
        operationBinding.execute();
    }
}

public void editPopupCancelListener(PopupCanceledEvent popupCanceledEvent) {
    BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
    OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("Rollback");
    operationBinding.execute();
}

public BindingContainer getBindings() {
    return BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
}
public void editPopupFetchListener1(PopupFetchEvent popupFetchEvent) {
    if (popupFetchEvent.getLaunchSourceClientId().contains("cbInsert1")) {
        BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
        OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("CreateInsert1");
        operationBinding.execute();
    }
}

public void editDialogListener1(DialogEvent dialogEvent) {
    if (dialogEvent.getOutcome().name().equals("ok")) {
        BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
        OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("Commit");
        operationBinding.execute();   
    } else if (dialogEvent.getOutcome().name().equals("cancel")) {
        BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
        OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("Rollback");
        operationBinding.execute();
    }
}

public void editPopupCancelListener1(PopupCanceledEvent popupCanceledEvent) {
    BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
    OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("Rollback");
    operationBinding.execute();
}

public BindingContainer getBindings1() {
    return BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
}

}
```

хотелось бы сделать небольшой код, но как сделать так,что бы при нажатии кнопок с разными id "cbInset,cbInsert1,cbInsert3" программа понимала что для всех этих кнопок нужно вызывать один метод,никак не могу понять(((

Comment: А почему обработка именно на editPopupFetch? Нельзя использовать actionListener на самой кнопке?

Comment: Пример брал отсюда http://andrejusb.blogspot.ru/2009/11/crud-operations-in-oracle-adf-11g-table.html

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно все понял то мой код полностью должен выглядеть именно так:

```
package view;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import oracle.adf.model.BindingContext;
import oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.data.RichTable;
import oracle.adf.view.rich.context.AdfFacesContext;
import oracle.adf.view.rich.event.DialogEvent;
import oracle.adf.view.rich.event.PopupCanceledEvent;
import oracle.adf.view.rich.event.PopupFetchEvent;
import oracle.binding.BindingContainer;
import oracle.binding.OperationBinding;
import org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.event.ReturnEvent;

public class Main {


private static CharSequence test;

public Main() {
    super();
}

public void editPopupFetchListener(PopupFetchEvent popupFetchEvent) {
    if (popupFetchEvent.getLaunchSourceClientId().contains("cbInsert")) { //проверяем что нажата кнопка Insert (т.е. id содержит "cbInsert")

        //С помощью регулярного выражения ищем индекс нажатой кнопки
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("cbInsert(.*)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
        m.find();
        String idIndex = m.group(1);

        BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
        OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("CreateInsert" + idIndex); //Ищем operationBinding по его id +  индекс
        operationBinding.execute();
    }
    }

public void editDialogListener(DialogEvent dialogEvent) {
    if (dialogEvent.getOutcome().name().equals("ok")) {
        BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
        OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("Commit");
        operationBinding.execute();   
    } else if (dialogEvent.getOutcome().name().equals("cancel")) {
        BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
        OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("Rollback");
        operationBinding.execute();
    }
}

public void editPopupCancelListener(PopupCanceledEvent popupCanceledEvent) {
    BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
    OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("Rollback");
    operationBinding.execute();
}

public BindingContainer getBindings() {
    return BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
}
    }
```

Comment: все равно не работает((( укажите на мою ошибку что я не так делаю(((

Answer (score 0):

Если делать на основе этого примера, я бы предложил следующий вариант (ограничение: идентификаторы кнопок и `operationBinding` на всех таблицах одинаковы и отличаются только порядковым номером):

```
public void editPopupFetchListener(PopupFetchEvent popupFetchEvent) {
    if (popupFetchEvent.getLaunchSourceClientId().contains("cbInsert")) { //проверяем что нажата кнопка Insert (т.е. id содержит "cbInsert")

        //С помощью регулярного выражения ищем индекс нажатой кнопки
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("cbInsert(.*)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
        m.find();
        String idIndex = m.group(1);

        BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
        OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("CreateInsert" + idIndex); //Ищем operationBinding по его id +  индекс
        operationBinding.execute();
    }
}
```

Но в реальной разработке я бы, конечно, такой способ не стал использовать.

Comment: Если не сложно напишите как лучше и правильней сделать?